# Loading LLM model on Media Pipe Studio

Tags: mediapipe, gemma

I seem to be having some problem loading the model on the LLM Inference page.

https://mediapipe-studio.webapps.google.com/studio/demo/llm_inference

After downloading Gemma from Kaggle I tried loading the config.json file, but it didn't work. Do I need a .bin file?

This is not a WebGPU error, I'm using Opera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the TensorFlow Lite Tab [image] then select the [gemma-2b-it-gpu-int4](https://www.kaggle.com/models/google/gemma/frameworks/tfLite/variations/gemma-2b-it-gpu-int4) variation and download it. The downloaded file is an `archive.tar.gz` when you decompress it, you will get a `gemma-2b-it-gpu-int4.bin` this is the file you need to select in the mediapipe studio.
I hope it helps :)